# Meaning of "тренироваться на кошечках"

Tags: идиомы

I Listened to a podcast, in which the speaker attempted to explain what **тренироваться на кошечках** means and how it's used, yet I failed to grasp the meaning. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Means "to train on a dummy" or "to practice the skills on a much simpler case".

Having been born back in the USSR and still being widely used by all generations, except may be the very old, it's quite a resilient meme from a film called "Операция Ы". Here's the scene where it's used: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-j79mA_6BAQ).

It can be employed quite liberally in all sorts of conversations -- you can have a dialogue that goes like this:

> -- Давай поднимемся на Эверест?
>
> -- Может, сначала потренируемся на кошечках и покорим Эльбрус?

Comment: Aha! This is what we call a "dry run": A: Hey, let's go climb Mt. Everest! B: Maybe we should do a dry run and conquer Elbrus first?

Comment: This dialog is impossible in real life but you could meet such constructed phrases in graphomaniac style writings where authors want to show theirs "sense of humor".

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij Disagreed. If you google real-life examples how this phrase is used today -- in blogs, facebook posts, etc., i.e. in modern colloquial speech -- you'll find out that nothing stops someone from using the phrase in a dialogue that I made up. The dialogue is in a sense hyperbolic -- I don't really expect anyone to use the phrase with respect to things like Everest and Elbrus. But it's hyperbolic on purpose -- I wanted to show that there are virtually no boundaries as to how this phrase can be employed when one wants to refer to an easier situation.

Comment: in blogs, facebook posts - it is exactly a perfects samples of " graphomaniac style writings "

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij Well, it's modern colloquial speech... If people write like this, one should expect them to talk like this too. I think....

Answer (score 1):

The only useful form in spoken language is direct movie citation: "тренеруйся на кошках".

Source is this movie, this episode: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s9aJqeeNVBQ

When this phrase could have a meaning "to train on a dummy" in real life dialog it is always a joke and  almost never used for something else then friendly bulling: "you have no skill, find other fool :P".

Also to hear it you should directly trigger word "тренироваться": "я тренирую..", "я собираюсь тренивать.." .

E.g. playing chess with a friend, if you would comment you first moves: "this time I'm going train my King's Gambit" you would get back "тренируйся (лучше) на кошках" probably nine times out of ten.